# Getting delay in Mongo DB with updateOne

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query

I am updating few fields in a document with java and updates get complete with in 4ms.
I am going to db to fetch same documentjust after the update completes. I am not getting updated documents.
Any reason why I am not getting updated Document?
Few things i tried are

1. I tried updateOne Method it shows modified document 1
2. findOneAndUpdate method option of ReturnDocument.AFTER and it returns updated document.
   Issue is When after 2 ms my process goes to updated document then updated Document is not there.

Configuration are Read Concern as majority, Write concern as majority and read preference as Primary.

Comment: Sounds like you need causally consistent sessions: https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/core/read-isolation-consistency-recency/#client-sessions-and-causal-consistency-guarantees

Answer (score 0):

Below factor's might you have to check:

1. **Write Concern:**
   Double-check that your write concern is set right. If you're using `WriteConcern.MAJORITY`, it ensures most replica set members acknowledge the write, but it doesn't promise immediate visibility for reads.

   ```java
   WriteConcern.MAJORITY
   ```
2. **Read Concern:**
   Make sure your read concern is set to `majority` for consistent results reflecting the latest majority-committed write.

   ```java
   ReadConcern.MAJORITY
   ```
3. **Indexing:**
   Check if your query/update fields are properly indexed for better read performance.
4. **Check for Errors:**
   After the `updateOne` operation, log the result and check for errors.

   ```java
   UpdateResult result = collection.updateOne(filter, update);
   if (!result.wasAcknowledged()) {
       // Handle error
   }
   ```
5. **Connection Pooling:**
   Confirm your MongoDB Java driver uses connection pooling for efficiency.
6. **Replica Set Status:**
   Verify the health of your MongoDB replica set. Ensure all nodes are okay, and there's no replication lag.